# Pass string value in socket.io

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

After I am passing any string value the server is getting disconnected. The server only accept number in *node.js*.

```
io = sio.listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    if ((new String(msg)).toString('utf-8') === 'utf-8') {
        socket.send(msg);
        console.log("Bye bye!\n");
        socket.disconnect();
    } else  {
        console.log('Received: ', msg);
        messages.push(msg);
        io.sockets.emit('chat message', msg);
    }
});
```

I tried this code. But it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: You're missing a `});` at the end of your code. Also, what ere you trying to do? Is there any error message? What php have to do with it? Also, your if will always be wrong unless you send `utf-8`, is that supposed to act like that?

Comment: hai DrakaSan,server only accept number not string..when i give some string value the server automatically disconnecting..

Comment: Please provide a client code example also. Are you sure you don't want simply `typeof msg === 'string'`? In the docs I only see the `send` method used client side, perhaps you can try `socket.emit('chat message', msg);` server side??

Comment: hai Kevin that code not working

Answer (score 0):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
 $('form').submit(function(){
 socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
 $('#m').val();
 return false;
 });
 var datavar=1;
 socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
 $('#messages').append(msg); });
```

this is client side code...